# Writing test cases for another web service

Tags: java, web-services, testing, functional-testing

I'm working in a team as a developer. We have developed a product where we generate letters by populating some XML file. This XML file **ONLY** contains some texts that need to show up in a pdf document.  We then send this XML across to a different area via a web service (say **WS-A**) call.

This WS-A returns a generated PDF document as a byte stream. Please note that beside generating a pdf document, the backend of WS-A is responsible for the pdf template and how and where these XML texts are displayed in the document. Everything up to this point is fine.

I also do understand that our team needs to write test cases to make sure the correct XML contents are populated before sending it through WS-A.

My question is, is writing a test case which verifies this pdf has the right "**texts**" (*only text verification*) our team's responsibility?

Or is this something the other team (in charge of WS-A backend) has to test to make sure they don't miss anything in their PDF from the XML they have been provided (before sending it back to us as a byte stream)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no as, it sounds to me like it is a shared responsibility.

As the developer, it is you and your teams job to make sure that you are sending the correct XML template and data.  Where your responsibility ends, is once the data has been sent to the backend and the PDF has been generated.  It sounds to me that the text being sent can vary so, I would just let the other team handle that since the variance is likely from their side of things.

Comment: we're already verifying the XML content before sending it over to WS-A. Do we need to do anything further?

Comment: @MohammadNajar - In my experience, no.  The wording of your post leads me to believe that the other team pulls the content from the database and places it into the template that your team creates.  If that is true, the onus of verifying that is on their end.